# LyX - import from .tex - incompatible theorems - workaround

Tags: lyx, conversion

There are various problems converting .tex files to .lyx files. If you try for a simple document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Test

\begin{thm}
Test theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

LyX doesn't seem to recognize the theorem environments and puts them in red boxes. I used LyX to write up complicated equations because I find it faster, and I would like to convert between formats.

I have found an annoying workaround. Add theorems (AMS) in modules. Then, create any theorem using the dropdown menu in LyX. Export the document to .tex, then import again to LyX. This causes all theorems, lemma, etc. to be displayed properly. However this is clearly not ideal.

I also tried to use 'Edit->Paste special->Paste from LaTeX'. However this results in an error: "Could not move a temporary file from etc1.lyx to etc2.lyx".

Comment: Does `File -> Import -> LaTeX (plain)` work?

Comment: If you have already made a bug report about this (which you could have mentioned: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10432), why post here as well? (Bug reports are generally off topic around here.)

Comment: file->import->latex (plain) is what I used. It doesn't work. I thought it would be on topic because conversion and lyx are tags. I posted here because I didn't get any response, and this community is pretty active and large. I didn't mention that I filed a bug report because I didn't think it was relevant. If I get a response there, I will post here.

Comment: 1) Well yes, most LyX questions are on-topic, but *bug reports* are not. 2) It's less than a day since you posted that bug-report, even in today's world you can't always expect responses in that time frame. 3) Large community perhaps, but I don't think there are that many LyX power users around unfortunately. (Think there are some though.) 4) Mentioning cross-posting is always relevant. 5) A small tip: To make sure a user is notified of your comment, use `@username` (when you start typing the username should pop up, and you can hit Tab to complete it), you can only @-ping one user per comment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: 1) Well it might not even be a bug: I may just be doing something wrong. 2) It's not unreasonable to have to wait more than a day obviously. I just didn't see any reason not to try here too.

Comment: As stated by OP and clased invalid in bug tracker this is not a bug just a non standard workaround for one way of working